# Convert curl to HTTP request for Stripe api

Tags: http, curl, get, stripe-payments, urlencode

I was trying to run the [stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/search) in postman, and I don't know how to set   --data-urlencode correctly. Any ideas?

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges/search \
  -u sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc: \
  --data-urlencode query="amount>999 AND metadata['order_id']:'6735'" \
  -G
```

What's the http version for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Postman lets you choose the encoding straight in their UI under the `Body` section:

[image: configuration]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I noticed that, but per the stripe api, they are using "GET" with --data-urlencode, you can see it from above command `-G` specified. That's why I don't know why? Is it possible you ran it successfully in the postman?

Comment: You don't need to do anything specific with the GET parameters, they get URL encoded automatically